# Previously working code using 'tidy::pivot_longer' returns : "Error: `cols` must select at least one column"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

I had some code that was working where I was using `pivot_longer` to shift a list of columns into a long format. It was working fine but now I am getting "Error: `cols` must select at least one column."

I had been using the function in combination with `map_df` to combine mutiple .csv files in the following way:

```
Data set 1
   X        date distance.code location.code Time1     unneeded.data
   1 2021/05/18             C          BSF1 0.715               999
   2 2021/05/18            30          BSF1 0.896               999
   3 2021/05/18            60          BSF1 0.803               999
   4 2021/05/18           120          BSF1 0.705               999
   5 2021/05/18             C          BSG1 0.563               999
   6 2021/05/18             C          BSG1 0.961               999
   7 2021/05/18            30          BSG1 0.833               999
   8 2021/05/18            60          BSG1 0.894               999
 
data set 2                                                                        
  X       date distance.code location.code  Time2     unneeded data
  1 2021/05/18             C          BSF1 0.806               999
  2 2021/05/18            30          BSF1 0.878               999
  3 2021/05/18            60          BSF1 0.625               999
  4 2021/05/18           120          BSF1 0.609               999
  5 2021/05/18             C          BSG1 0.766               999
  6 2021/05/18             C          BSG1 0.846               999
  7 2021/05/18            30          BSG1 0.856               999
  8 2021/05/18            60          BSG1 0.698               999

Combined datasets (this is what I want)                                                                           
  X       date distance.code location.code        timeperiod   Values
  1 2021/05/18             C          BSF1             Time1 0.715
  2 2021/05/18            30          BSF1             Time1 0.896
  3 2021/05/18            60          BSF1             Time1 0.803
  4 2021/05/18           120          BSF1             Time1 0.705
  5 2021/05/18             C          BSG1             Time1 0.563
  6 2021/05/18             C          BSG1             Time1 0.961
  7 2021/05/18            30          BSG1             Time1 0.833
  8 2021/05/18            60          BSG1             Time1 0.894
  1 2021/05/18             C          BSF1             Time2 0.806
  2 2021/05/18            30          BSF1             Time2 0.878
  3 2021/05/18            60          BSF1             Time2 0.625
  4 2021/05/18           120          BSF1             Time2 0.609
  5 2021/05/18             C          BSG1             Time2 0.766
  6 2021/05/18             C          BSG1             Time2 0.846
  7 2021/05/18            30          BSG1             Time2 0.856
  8 2021/05/18            60          BSG1             Time2 0.698
```

The [first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69444634/can-a-column-of-data-from-several-csv-files-stored-in-the-same-folder-be-comp) I got help with this the code that was suggested was:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp,read.csv)

cols_to_keep <- c('X', 'date','distance.code', 'location.code')

combine_data <- map_df(myfiles, ~.x %>% 
      select(all_of(cols_to_keep), starts_with('Time')) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Time'), 
                   names_to = 'timeperiod', 
                   values_to = 'Values'))
```

It worked perfectly a few times but then I went back to it and it did not work any longer.

I had modified it somewhat but it had worked in the modified form as well.
Here is how I had modified it:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(qpcR)

temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp,read.csv)
cols_to_keep <- c('date','distance.code', 'location.code', 'samp.rate', 'sound.files', 'start.times.of.file', 'experiment.start.time')
combine_data <- map_df(myfiles, ~.x %>% 
                         dplyr::select(all_of(cols_to_keep), starts_with('h.values')) %>%
                         pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('h.values'), 
                                      names_to = 'timeperiod',
                                      values_to = 'Values'))
```

I don't really understand why this error started. I found some reference to a similar problem on Github but there was not a clear solution.

What can I do to make this code work again?
Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Hard to test without sample data in the form of code (vs. it's printed appearance which you've shared). Can you include the output of `dput(head(myfiles))`?

Comment: You might also look at the result of `combine_data <- map_df(myfiles, ~.x %>% dplyr::select(all_of(cols_to_keep), starts_with('h.values'))` just prior to the `pivot_longer` step -- Does it run and have the columns you expect?

Comment: Try running `lapply(myfiles, names)` do you get the expected column names ?

Comment: When I looked at the items in the list `myfiles` I saw that there were two unexpected items in the list. These came from .csv files that I added into my working directory which were aromatically getting incorporated with the command `list.files`. Once I removed them from the working directory the code worked again! Thanks @JonSpring and @RonakShah both of your suggestions helped me figure this out. Not sure if this constitutes an answer to the question.